# How can I evaluate my technique?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am dealing with a problem of text summarization i.e. given a large chunk(s) of text, I want to find the most representative "topics" or the subject of the text. For this, I used various information theoretic measures such as TF-IDF, Residual IDF and Pointwise Mutual Information to create a "dictionary" for my corpus. This dictionary contains important words mentioned in the text.

I manually sifted through the entire 50,000 list of phrases sorted on their TFIDF measure and hand-picked 2,000 phrases (I know! It took me 15 hours to do this...) that are the ground truth i.e. these are important for sure. Now when I use this as a dictionary and run a simple frequency analysis on my text and extract the top-k phrases, I am basically seeing what the subject is and I agree with what I am seeing.

Now how can I evaluate this approach? There is no machine learning or classification involved here. Basically, I used some NLP techniques to create a dictionary and using the dictionary alone to do simple frequency analysis is giving me the topics I am looking for. However, is there a formal analysis I can do for my system to measure its accuracy or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert of machine learning, but I would use **[cross-validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29)**. If you used e.g. 1000 pages of text to "train" the algorithm (there is a "human in the loop", but no problem), then you could take another few hundred test pages, and use your "top-k phrases algorithm" to find the "topic" or "subject" of these. The **ratio of test pages where you agree with the outcome** of the algorithm gives you a (somewhat subjective) measure of how well your method performs.

Comment: If I understand you right, you have a software, which can frequency analyze a text page, and give you keywords - this means that you do have an algorithm :) Throw in few hundred pages, and collect the keyword set for each. Then read each page and decide whether the keyword set properly describes the topic of the text. To avoid your personal bias, get volunteers to evaluate the goodness of the keyword set on a 1-to-10 scale. You could also put the texts and their keywords on the web, and use crowdsourcing.

Comment: +1 Interesting! The only problem now is to find volunteers to do this as it is a very domain-specific problem (medical) so basic crowdsourcing may be difficult to work with as it is hard to find volunteers. Will find some good crowdsourcing approaches. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes. Definitely taking that path for now. :)